# Как распарсить GSON в массив?

Tags: android

Посоветуйте как распарсить GSON в массив. Ссылка на GSON: http://cache-minsk03.cdn.yandex.net/download.cdn.yandex.net/mobilization-2016/artists.json

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно создать класс, описывающий вашу модель объекта.
Добавьте в зависимости в gradle gson.

```
compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+"
```

Затем получите вашу строку json'a, а потом:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
OurModel[] arrayOfOurModels = gson.fromJson(jsonString, OurModel[].class);
```

где OurModel - это модель, описывающая вашу сущность в json

```
public class OurModel {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int tracks;
    private int albums;
    private String link;
    private String description;

    private CoverEntity cover;
    private List<String> genres;


    public static class CoverEntity {
        private String small;
        private String big;
    }
}
```

[image: Здесь вы можете посмотреть структуру своего json http://json.parser.online.fr/]

Comment: Что значить получить вашу строку json"a? И как это вы создали Ourmodel? покуда непонятно может книжка какая небудь есть?

Comment: Когда вы переходите по ссылке, которую вы дали в описании, открывается Html страничка с текстом, вот это и есть ваша строка json'a

Comment: OurModel я создал по вашему josn объект, скопируйте весь ваш json и вставте сюда http://json.parser.online.fr/ увидите вашу структуру

Comment: можно еще последний врпрос  копирую я  отсюда  http://cache-minsk03.cdn.yandex.net/download.cdn.yandex.net/mobilization-2016/artists.json    вставляю сюда json.parser.online.fr

Comment: А в чем собственно ваш вопрос?

Comment: cпасибо помогли.